# Dynamically managing height of iscroll-wrapper in iscrollview.js

Tags: jquery-mobile, iscrollview

In my app. I am using **iScrollview.js**,to achieve smooth scrolling on touch screen devices.

**iScrollview.js** calculates height of iscroll-wrapper by this way :

```
$wrapper.height()+$pullDown.outerHeight()+$pullUp.outerHeight
```

In one view there is an accordion structure.  When the accordion is expanded, I am unable to scroll properly due to the load-time height calculation of iscroll-wrapper.
I think this is due to the height of whole page being less than that of the accordion structure.

Can you please advise how to manage the height of iscroll-wrapper dynamically?